# WooCommerce: Add a product attribute to the existing ones in a product

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, attributes, product

I am struggling with adding an attribute to a product.

I have an array of keywords that I would like to add to a product:

```
$clean_keywords = array('cake','cup cakes');
$term_taxonomy_ids = wp_set_object_terms( get_the_ID(), $clean_keywords, 'pa_keywords', true );
$thedata = Array('pa_keywords' => Array(
    'name' => 'pa_keywords',
    'value' => '',
    'is_visible' => '0',
    'is_taxonomy' => '1'
));

update_post_meta( get_the_ID(),'_product_attributes',$thedata);
```

This works fine, but it deletes all my other attributes attach to the product.

I think the solution is to get the current attributes and merge it with `$thedata` variable... but not sure how to do this.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to get existing product attributes first and insert your new product attribute in the array before saving it. Also I have added 2 missing arguments in the array…

So your code should be:

```
$product_id = get_the_ID();
$taxonomy = 'pa_keywords';
$clean_keywords = array('cake','cup cakes');
$term_taxonomy_ids = wp_set_object_terms( $product_id, $clean_keywords, $taxonomy, true );

// Get existing attributes
$product_attributes = get_post_meta( $product_id, '_product_attributes', true);

// get the count of existing attributes to set the "position" in the array
$count = count($product_attributes);

// Insert new attribute in existing array of attributes (if there is any)
$product_attributes[$taxonomy] = array(
    'name' => $taxonomy,
    'value' => '',
    'position' => $count, // added
    'is_visible' => '0',
    'is_variation' => '0', // added (set the right value)
    'is_taxonomy' => '1'
);

// Save the data
update_post_meta( $product_id, '_product_attributes', $product_attributes );
```

This should work now without removing existing data.

Comment: just figured out how to do that... Thanks again